# Laravel Scheduler with multi timezone handling

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing ERP project in cloud base & I am using one source for multiple customers and using different database.

I want to run script every day at 00:00 with different time-zone

Here what i tried......

> This is my `Kernel` class

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('attendance:null')->hourly();
}
```

> This is my attendance:null command class

```
class AttendanceInsertNull extends Command{

protected $signature = 'attendance:null';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Command description';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return \App\Console\Commands\AttendanceInsertNull
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $locations = Location::get();

    foreach ($locations as $location) {

            $schedule1 = new Schedule();
            $schedule1->call(function(){

                $timeZone = $location->timezone;

                $this->info('RUN');

            })->at('00:00')->timezone($timeZone);
    }
}
```

}

What i am doing is, Check with different timezone in location loop.

please anyone can help to solve this issue for me.

Comment: Why do you need to call the scheduler again? Since you're running it every hour, you can just check to see if it is `00:00` in one of the timezones you are supporting. If so, run your business logic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are u asking me to add a if condition in handle function

Comment: Pretty much, you don't need to create another scheduler. You are already running your command every hour, so at some point, it will hit `00:00` in each of your timezones. It's just a matter of checking to see if it is `00:00` in each timezone per hour it runs.

Comment: Thanks i have got your point I will check..